# Issue in displaying date field data correctly in Lightning component list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to show the below in lightning component(list):

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!ext.Last_Activity_Date__c}" 
                             year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"/>
```

In lightning it shows date one day before than the actual date.

Adding `timeZone="{! $Locale.timezone }` to the above doesn't work for me. `Last_Activity_Date__c` is custom date field

Can someone please help or suggest some other way !

Comment: The `locale` set in User's Preferences determines how the value is formatted. What is the running User's settings?

Comment: Also important, did you check that the "Last Activity Date" was set in your own timezone and not in the timezone of a user who's a day ahead of you? It's entirely possible that, once corrected for timezone difference, your date is correctly displayed.